# Arrange dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of gene mutation loci for different genes. I would like to rearrange the dataframe so that each row only has one value and that value is arranged from lowest to highest from the entire dataframe. I have an abbreviated example below.

Here is how it currently looks:

```
a=c('1', '2', '5')
b=c('1', '2', '7')
c=c('5', '6', NA)
df=data.frame(a,b,c)

   A  B  C 
1  1  1  5
2  2  2  6
3  5  7  NA
```

Here is how I would like it to look:

```
   A  B  C  
1  1  1  NA
2  2  2  NA
3  5  NA 5
4  NA NA 6
5  NA 7  NA
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You prob want `setNames(do.call(rbind.data.frame, list(b,c,d)),a)` as your example data frame syntax

Comment: Your data set doesn't look like you are claiming it is. Try running your own code.

Comment: I have fixed the errors in the code to reflect the correct output. Thanks.

Comment: Are your values are charters or real numbers? There is a difference between `5` and `'5'`. Also, you had originally a `dplyr` tag because you wanted a `dplyr` answer or any answer is fine?

Comment: *I would like to rearrange the dataframe so that each row only has one value and that value is arranged from lowest to highest from the entire dataframe.* That does not make sense when looking at your data.  Some of your output rows have more than one value and you cannot arrange one value from lowest to highest  anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a possible solution

```
v1 <- sort(unlist(lapply(df, function(x) 
            unique(x[!is.na(x)])), use.names=FALSE))
l1 <- length(unique(v1))
m1 <- matrix(, ncol=ncol(df), nrow=l1)
lst <- split(v1, v1)
i1 <- rep(seq_along(lst), lengths(lst))
j1 <- unlist(lapply(lst, function(x) which(df==unique(x),
             arr.ind=TRUE)[,2]), use.names=FALSE)
m1[cbind(i1,j1)] <- v1
m1
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    1   NA
# [2,]    2    2   NA
# [3,]    5   NA    5
# [4,]   NA   NA    6
# [5,]   NA    7   NA
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 2L, 5L), B = c(1L, 2L, 
 7L), C = c(5L, 
6L, NA)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `recast` to melt and cast the data frame. We can use `!is.na(value)` to remove the `NA` values as a unique row:

```
library(reshape2)
recast(df, value[!is.na(value)]~variable[!is.na(value)])[-1]
#    A  B  C
# 1  1  1 NA
# 2  2  2 NA
# 3  5 NA  5
# 4 NA NA  6
# 5 NA  7 NA
```

Comment: You could use `na.rm=TRUE` in `melt` `dcast(melt(df, na.rm=TRUE), value~variable)[-1]` .  Though it worked on the example, I am not sure in other cases.

Comment: For the cases I tested, it worked.  This is a nice, compact option (I never thought this way).  But, with `gather/spread` I couldn't get the right output.